# Why does my website download instead of open?

Tags: html, download, ejs

So I just started a new project and the file keeps downloading when I try to open localhost. There is barely anything in this project this is my whole server:

```
// initialize server
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.engine(".ejs", require("ejs").__express);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static(__dirname+"views"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"public"));

// start server
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("listening on port 3000")
});

// get html
app.get("/start", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/views/homepage.ejs")
});
```

I also have the homepage.ejs with only a text "hello" and empty folders views and public>css. When I set it up I could open the homepage after I wrote the server code and created the folders (it showed the text, everything worked) but when I tried to create a stylesheet and color the background of my homepage it downloaded. I then deleted the css sheet and restarted the server, it keeps downloading. I'm working on bigger projects via github and I never had that problem it just happens when I'm on my own projects. I tried copying some older small projects of mine which always worked but as soon as I change a few things (doesn't matter what) it downloads again. I have the folders in my OneDrive so I opened them on my laptop, same problem. I opened them in other browsers (Chrome, Explorer, Firefox) same problem. Does anyone know how to fix it pls?

Edit: javascript project in vs code if that helps

Comment: You're not gonna be able to run these from OneDrive or a `file:///` URL. You need a proper server configured to run this.

Comment: I just want to open them in localhost it worked with every other project i had but since a couple of days everything just downloads even the projects that worked in the past and it did open first but after a couple of minutes it starts downloading as if there was a timer to it?

Comment: How are you running the code? `node <your file>.js`? Or do you have an existing webserver you're trying to access it with?

Comment: yes i run it with node server.js